# Reading file into array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, visual-c++

I am trying to simply read a file "input.txt" into an array people[]. The txt file has 3 numbers:

```
10
20
30
```

I am getting -9.25596e+61 instead of 10 for people[0]. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Trip {
private:

    double people[3];

public:
    void readFile(string file);
};

void Trip::readFile(string file) {
    ifstream input;
    input.open(file);
    input >> people[0] >> people[1] >> people[2];
    cout << people[0];
    input.close();

}



int main() {
    Trip trip;
    trip.readFile("input.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check if the file is actually opened, or if the `cin` failed for any reason.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `std::vector` instead of C-style fixed-length arrays.

Comment: Always, always check if files open successfully. It clearly isn't in your case. The most likely reason for that is that the program is looking for input.txt in a different place to where you put the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is correct. Working fine.

Currently, it is not getting the file. So, it is failing for you.

Provide the fully qualified path to readFile() as below example:

```
Path like "C:\\Users\\source\\Temp\\x64\\Debug\\input.txt"
```

Windows support file path with backward or forward slashes:

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx